# Java paths in netbeans with maven

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans

I'm trying to refer to a properties file in my NetBeans project using Maven.

While developing, I used the following code:

```
MyClass.loadProperties("src/main/resources/neo4j.properties");
```

This worked fine.

Now that I've just built my project to a JAR, when I execute it, it complains that it can't find this file.

I don't want the file to be in the JAR file - I'd really just like to be able to specify a location to load the properties file from - probably the same directory as the main JAR.

What path should I use? In fact, I'm not clear on how this works at all - I ran into a similar issue with a previous project.

I think the src/main/resources is specific to Maven isn't it? When a JAR is running, are all directories relative to the one in which the JAR is located?

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is this *MyClass.loadProperties* method ?

Yes, the *src/main/resources* is a maven convention to put resources, see [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

So the files in this directory **are** in the app jar. You get them throw a resource protocol, not a file protocol.

If you want some config files in another place, and not in a jar, you need to construct a policy yourself. For instance in the home directory, in a user choice folder, on the net, in a directory on the classpath, in a preference thing...

**edit :** To get a config file in a local directory throw a resource thing, you need to put this directory in the classpath.

Comment: thanks. how do i load them through a resource? i've been trying to use file paths...

Comment: I edit my post to answer. But I think it's not a good way ; it's best to put a config file in the jar (so in the appli and in the classpath), or put it in a local user directory outside the classpath, so to memorize the config path in a preference or in some conventional way.

Comment: +1, this answer was helpful to me to convert a Netbeans generated JDesktop application to Maven (which otherwise failed with a `NullPointerException` when trying to get values using a `ResourceMap`.